Simplified page view with URL
Earlier there was a Google url https://www.google.com/reader/view/?url= where one got a simplified page view of any url. Now this service is dead - you get just a 404.
Does somebody know something similar? My goal is to get simplified page view, an AMP-like version or just a forced reader view.
I need it as url or forced by Javascript. I can't access Chromium's DOM Distiller because of don't having access to Chromium flags.

Won't give as an answer, as it seems wonkier than the core browser equivalents (not that any are perfect) but this might work for your needs - https://clearthis.page/?u=

If you rely on a third party service there's always a risk it may be removed. You didn't say why you wanted us this service nor how you use it - so is very significant for framing an answer. Firefox's reader mode might meet your requirement.

@symcbean big question. I scrape pages to calculate embeddings. I need clean pages - but not without semantic markup. Screaming Frog's Chromium doesnt let me access flags to activate dom distiller.

@RichardB very pity, but doesn't work - shoot pages in pieces.
